# What is the difference using async/await and Task for time critical processing?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

Lets say I have a method that is constantly receiving input every 10ms, adds data to a `Queue<T>`, another thread dequeues and does some processing and writes to a file to keep everything flowing in nicely.  The reason for this is because processing will take longer than 10ms.

In updating this method with .Net 4 I would start a new Task with the long running option to ensure a new thread is created. Have a `BlockingCollection<T>` to add data to and in the task method have the `BlockingCollection` call `GetConsumingEnumerable` to process data and write this to file.

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure if I need the Task to create a new thread or not but due to my ignorance this seems the most beneficial way of doing it.

Secondly with the introduction of `async` and `await` keywords I could possibly rewrite this again so that when data comes in, call a method marked with `async` which does processing and then calls `await FileStream.WriteAsync`. Will this ensure that the data coming in at 10ms apart is handled ok and there is no back log? I have found that these new keywords don't create new threads but just handles execution in a timely manner somehow.

In my scenario will this be any good to me or should I stick to creating new threads with the long running Task and BlockingCollection?

Comment: Your question is unclear - where does the `FileStream` come in? Please clarify your overall scenario, as well as whether you can *actually* process the input as fast as it arrives.

Comment: @JonSkeet The FileStream is just my indication that I am writing to file using the new asynchronous functions available. The reason processing is done on another thread/task is because the processing will be longer than 10ms. Have updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're receiving input every 10ms and processing takes longer than 10ms, then you will not be able to keep up unless you're doing parallel processing on the back end.

It sounds like a producer/consumer approach is best for your situation. You can use `BlockingCollection<T>` with separate threads/tasks, but you should also consider the [Dataflow library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=205053) (part of the new VS Async support). The Dataflow library allows you to set up a pipeline (or mesh) that defines how your data flows through the system; tasks are automatically created as needed.

Comment: I know you can use BlockingCollection without a new thread but I'm not sure how it works if not on another thread to keep the input and the processing all working seamlessly. I know Tasks are supposed to handle that internally and assess things but sounds a bit scary and you're not guaranteed anything whereas if you know you have a dedicated thread all should be ok!

Comment: The Dataflow documentation is very clear on how it behaves, and there's a ton of options you can pass in to change its behavior. Dataflow does not use `BlockingCollection` AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The async and await keywords are meant to help you writing asynchronous calls to functions/APIs that take long to respond. The compiler wraps to call in 2 methods, the one that launches the task and the one that is the callback when the call is done.

In your case it seems there is no point in using async and await since you are launching a separate task to handle the work. There is no third thing that needs to happen after the work has been done.

Comment: I would have thought the async and await are designed for more than just doing stuff asynchronously and doing something when finished. I may be wrong though?

Comment: They were introduced because async applications are very hard to write when you have more than 1 asynchronous request. You have to remember all the asynchronous operations that have finished, and which results depend on which. This is much easier for the compiler to do automatically. Async tells the compiler the your function should be broken up into a few more, and await tells it exactly where the breaks should happen.